# Longer or any longer?

Tags: adverbs

If I can say this:

> Will you be doing it any longer?

What if I will say:

> Will you be doing it longer?

am I obliged to use "any" or it can exist without it? Would the sense change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Will you be doing it longer?" to me sounds like you're asking if I will be doing it longer than I did last time, or longer than someone else is doing it, or something like that.  "Will you be doing it any longer?" is clearly asking whether I will continue doing it, or stop.